# How do I make my text labels pop with a background rect in a Collapsible Tree Layout? (D3.js)

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, treeview, label

I'm making a UX walkthrough for my company that is going to look exactly like this: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

Now my tree is basically done, however we have a very verbose layout, so a lot of the text labels are overlapping. I'd like to append a rect behind the text (white rect on black text) so that it makes the text readable. **Even when the tree overlaps.**

Here is the link to my inline js:
https://gist.github.com/wiredsister/7087220

It seems like I can't have an SVG text tag be the child of a rect tag. Could I append them to the same g tag instead? Like:

```
var g = svg.append('g') 
g.append('rect') 
g.append('text')
```

Any help is appreciated :]

Comment: Try the code you've posted, it should work as expected.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, so I created a new g and appended both my rect and text to it, but it isn't keeping the same positioning. It looks like: http://imgur.com/njG3SOI -- this is what the new code looks like: https://gist.github.com/wiredsister/7089205

Comment: Try setting `text-anchor` to `middle`.